# IIS Reverse Proxy Fails without Trailing Slash

Tags: iis, tomcat, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I have IIS with URL Rewrites acting as a reverse proxy to Apache Tomcat.

example.com/app/ redirects to example.com:8080/app/. Port 80 redirects to port 8080 on the same server.

If I go to example.com/app/ it works as expected.  However, if I go to example.com/app (without the trailing slash), it results in a 404 error.

The pattern I'm matching for the Inbound Rule is `^app/(.*)`.  Then the action rewrites to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/{R:1}`.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work without the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and manage to fix it by creating two rules

1. 301 Redirect

search pattern: ^app$

redirect URL: app/

2. rewrite

search pattern: ^app/(.*)

rewrite URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/{R:1}

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Thomas's answer, here is the config file after the rules have been created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="app/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could work with a solution I used for a similar issue. In your case, the search pattern would be:

```
^app(/?|/.*)$
```

and the Rewrite URL would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/app{R:1}
```

Notice that there is no